# Gmail sidebar gadget using Google Apps Script > Refused to display

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have a simple Google Apps Script project as follow, published as a web app

Code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Button1');
}
```

Buttom1.html

```
<html>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var response = "Ok, Done" // do something that returns "Ok, Done" response
      var b = document.getElementById('result');
      b.innerHTML = response;
      document.getElementById('button1').disabled = 'disabled';
      return;
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <button onclick='myFunction()' id='button1'>Do IT Now!</button>
    <div id="result">Ready ...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Within Gmail > Settings > Labs > I enabled "Add any gadget by URL" and add a link to the following xml file representing a sidebar gadget associated with above web app project

```
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="Testing -GAS" />
  <Content type="url" href="https://script.google.com/a/macros/thexs.ca/s/AKfycbxvL43dfxJb82wxRST1bXIf08gSrVlbKt1W4Uxvy0QSq-SxFTA/exec" />
</Module>
```

I can only see the title of this gadget because Chrome is refusing to display the App in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Also note in the error message below, that there are a bunch of parameters added to the Url.

I know it's doable and probably trivial, but have No idea on how to fix this problem.

This is the error in the Chrome console:

```
Refused to display 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/thexs.ca/s/AKfycbxvL43dfxJb82wxRST1bXIf08gSrVlbKt1W4Uxvy0QSq-SxFTA/exec?container=gm&view=default&lang=en&country=CA&sanitize=0&v=6c3c95f52b62fa08&rpctoken=g5ik00zemwti&libs=core%3Aauth-refresh&parent=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fa%2Fthexs.ca%2Fhtml&pid=thexs.ca&mid=0&st=e%3DAA6WCYb%252F6JLIjQyyLJLyGaZcTWLgsk3YtjB0AWV9dNYxEmbptJBGKM5uhcb8yYlaL2%252FGk7M4%252Fu%252B1WJJgprkAjjlNELAYOoNkcAXOb9X4w%252B721DtB0RR%252FawL2Eo9%252BHSMp97FE6sy1kXk5%26c%3Dgm' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script Web Apps can currently only be inserted into Google Sites as gadgets because of cross domain restrictions on iframes. There is [an open issue ticket for this with more details and an opportunity to detail your use case](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2394)

There is a existing [related question on this topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808722/app-script-htmlservice-app-in-iframe)

Comment: thanks @mhawksey and would it be the same if 1) I use content type="html" and include a button that calls the web app OR 2) if that button makes a url-fetch to the web app?

Comment: @FaustoR. afraid not familiar with details of Gmail Gadget API

Comment: The open ticket is fixed