# Google Apps Script Web App on my Domain

Tags: google-apps-script

I had built a Google UI Apps Script in my Drive account. It works great.

I would like to embed it on my domain. I know that I can embed it as a gadget on a Google site, but I don't want Google's URL appearing in my website.

I have a word-press site and I would like to embed this UI script into a page/post on my word-press site or create a stand alone page on my domain with this script on it.

Is this possible?

I just don't want my users to be redirected off my site and see the long ugly domain of https://script.google.com/a/macros/*****************

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently supported.

See (duplicate) [Embedding Google Apps Script WebApp in WordPress Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350485/embedding-google-apps-script-webapp-in-wordpress-page).

Visit [Issue 852](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=852) and star it for updates. (There are also some potential work-arounds described in the issue comments.)