# is it possible to embed a google web app in a third party website?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

For my job, we are creating a google apps script based web app. However, our client would like to have the web app on their own personal appropriately-branded website. The problem is, from the "Web Apps and Google Sites Gadgets" page, I only see an option to embed web apps into Google Sites specifically, and can't find any info otherwise anywhere else. Does that mean that there is no way to embed into personal websites or is there a workaround that i'm not finding anywhere?

Thank you!

Comment: This [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17350485/851811) suggests it's not possible. However, the question is one year and a half old, and things may have changed. The related [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=852) on code.google.com seems to have some updates you may find useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use ContentService to use Apps Script as a backend.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service

On my webpage I use a call like:

```
   var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycb...vZ8SvFBRWo/exec?offset="+offset+"&baseDate="+baseDate+"&callback=?";
    $.getJSON( url, function( events ) { ...
```

In my script:

```
function doGet(e){
  var callback = e.parameter.callback; // required for JSONP
  .
  .
 return ContentService.createTextOutput(callback+'('+ JSON.stringify(returnObject)+')').setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}
```