# HTML service in a embedded SpreadSheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I made a spreadsheet with some scripts, and i'm using this code to show a custom sidebar with a Html form inside :

```
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setTitle('Choix de la période')    
SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
  .showSidebar(html);
```

I use a html file named "page.html".

This works perfectly when used directly in Google SpreadSheet, but I want to embed it in a website using an iframe :

```
<iframe src="my-googlesheet-URL" height="800" width="1200"></iframe>
```

When I use it while embedded like this, the sidebar is opening, but nothing is showing inside it (just a blank space).

I used the methods given on the google apps script official guides and didn't find a solution to make it work...
Can someone tell me if what i'm trying to do is possible, and if it is, how do I make it work ?

Thanks

Comment: Is your spreadsheet shared/public? Otherwise I think the content won't be visible.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the browsers console right after the sidebar opens?  I would remove the `.setTitle()` method just to see if it made any difference.

Comment: Removing .setTitle() doesn't change the problem. The spreadshit is shared : anyone with the link can edit. The other scripts work perfectly from the embedded page.

Comment: Thx for the browser console Tip, I didn't think of looking at it...It says It "refuse to display my spreadsheet in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."

Comment: possible duplicate of [App Script HTMLService App in iFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808722/app-script-htmlservice-app-in-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to embed a Google Sheet in a non-Google web site. You get the SAMEORIGIN message.

The only way to embed the sheet is by publishing it but this will not include your add-on.

To provide the best experience for your users they'll need to go directly to the sheet instead of using the embedded version you're wanting..